# How to define a var in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

Building my first real app with JS: Black Jack. I was just wondering why my `j`, `q`, `k`, and `a` var are coming back as `undefined`.

```
window.onload = init;
var cards = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,j,j,j,j,q,q,q,q,k,k,k,k,a,a,a,a];
var j = 10;
var q = 10;
var k = 10;
var a = 11;
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("doIt");
    button.onclick = processIt;
}
function processIt() {
    var cpu1 = document.getElementById("cpu1");
    cpu1.innerHTML = cards[37];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Because at the moment when you declare `cards`, those variables (or, rather, their values) are still undefined. Reorder the declarations.

```
var j = 10;
var q = 10;
var k = 10;
var a = 11;
var cards = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,j,j,j,j,q,q,q,q,k,k,k,k,a,a,a,a];
```

Comment: Strictly it's not about declarations because they happen before any code is executed, it's about assignment. At the moment the variables are used in the assignment to *cards*, their values are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining them after you use them... You have to define variables before you use them, not after.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, declarations are processed first but assignment occurs in order. Your code is effectively:

```
var cards, j, q, k, a;

// Here, all variables exist but none have a value
// When cards is assigned an array, the values of j, q, k and a 
// are still undefined.
cards = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,
         8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,j,j,j,j,q,q,q,q,k,k,k,k,a,a,a,a];

// Now the rest are given values
j = 10;
q = 10;
k = 10;
a = 11;
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns undefined: <br/> var a; <br/> cards = [2,2,...,a,a] <br/> a = 11; <br/> Would anyone mind explaining why it does this, couldn't find a good explanation in my book or Google.

Comment: The above explains why it happens. To not get undefined, assign values to the variables before using them (i.e. move the assignment to *cards* to after the assgnments to *j, q, k* and *a*).